# renumbering of a simple vector/integer/list in R

Tags: r, sorting

I'm a beginner in R programming. So maybe my question is too easy, but I coundn't find a proper answer in web. So I hope to get help here.
I have the following vector.

```
id_f<-c(52,69,78,52,99,41,69,7,34)
```

I want to get id, which can be present as follows:

```
id<-c(4,5,6,4,7,3,5,1,2)
```

I desire a renumbering and recounting of my original id_f object. 
Which command makes these reassingment?
Following assignment is desired:
7  --> 1, 34 --> 2, 41 --> 3, 52 --> 4, 69 --> 5, 78 --> 6, 99 --> 7.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: One wonders if you need a copy of the canonical Tom Short R cheatsheet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `match` used with `sort`:

```
> match(id_f, unique(sort(id_f)))
[1] 4 5 6 4 7 3 5 1 2
```

Comment: @user1317221_G, Thanks. I had deleted at first too because I hadn't thought to stick a `unique` in there. :-)

Comment: Isn't `sort(unique(.))` better (computationally) than `unique(sort(.))`?

Answer (score 2):

I found this problem annoying, hence my original answer didn't give you what you wanted. Here is one that wokrs for the sake of my own sanity! Althought there should be an easier way than `join` to preserve order and without the need for `data.frames`

```
> myids <- data.frame(id_f = c(52,69,78,52,99,41,69,7,34))
> id.hold <- data.frame( id_f = unique(id_f), ranks = rank(unique(id_f)) )
> library(plyr)
> join(myids, id.hold)[,2]
Joining by: id_f
[1] 4 5 6 4 7 3 5 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an overkill, but oh well:

```
library(data.table)

data.table(id_f)[order(id_f), rank := .GRP, by = id_f]$rank
#[1] 4 5 6 4 7 3 5 1 2
```

Comment: Very nice idea +1. The `order` part will use `base:::order` which might be slower on big data. But that'll be optimised soon.